# How to make sure I have odd or even number of inversions in my array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given the definition of inversion as below

***Inversions:***
Given a board, an inversion is any pair of tiles i and j where i < j but i appears after j when considering the board in row-major order (row 0, followed by row 1, and so forth).

[image]

I have an array like

`arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 22 , 5 , 12 , 3];`

and a function to count the number of inversions:

```
function getInvCount(arr){
let inv_count = 0;
for(let i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
    for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) inv_count++;
    }
}
return inv_count;
```

}

what I want to do is if the number of inversions is odd, make changes to the array so that it gives me an even number of inversions.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: By manually triggering a single inversion, perhaps?

Comment: Just swap two adjacent non-empty cells.

Comment: @raina77ow Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @trincot I thought about it, but that doesn't necessarily work. Those two elements might not even be an inversion, and even if they are, that number might have an inversion with the numbers before it too which again might make it an odd number

Comment: It is always an odd inversion provided that these two cells are horizontally or vertically adjacent. If you believe this is not true, please provide an example. Possibly you count inversions the wrong way because of "flattening" the grid to a one-dimensional array. But you should give details in your question.

Comment: How exactly should we guess what 'inversion' means in your case? @trincot assumed it's swapping of two tiles, and that was a fair guess; but if it's not, perhaps it's worth adding this detail? Until that, the question is not really clear; hence 3 'minus' votes given on it already.

Comment: @raina77ow You are right. Pardon me english is not my first language. I assumed inversion has only the meaning I had in mind. I will ask my question again

Comment: Please provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is about the game where you switch tiles as in your pictures, so you cannot just switch random elements in the array. In your case, any move changes the number of inversions by an even number. So it's not possible to change the odd number of inversions to even.